# Image Slider Isn't Responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, nivo-slider

I'm working with the Header Image Slider plugin for WordPress (which uses the Nivo Slider) and I can't seem to get the images to the size I need on a smaller screen.

I've looked around plenty and tried various things in my media queries like setting the max-width, but I can't put my finger on what the problem is. Each image is cutting off on the right-hand side. I'd like to get the images to roughly 708x245 on the next step-down. Any advice? Thanks!

[My Site](http://www.supportexcellence.org)

Comment: you need to set the width and height for each media query in your slider **slider.css.php** file to the right width and height for your content.. and then use !important on that CSS rule.. also or use the responsive version of NIVO slider.. since all inline styles of the NIVO slider are still at 960px width

Comment: also you have an error in the console:  SyntaxError: syntax error
http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflUEikS-.js
Line 128  <!DOCTYPE html> <!--[if IE 7]><html

Comment: Not sure what that error is in reference to...

I tried adding width and height values to .theme-default .nivoSlider and .theme-default .nivoSlider img in my queries to no avail.

Comment: you would have to target the nivo slider container, all slide images, and all the div's that create the transition FX .. that version of NIVO SLIDER is not the responsive version.. the author has a **responsive version** available - DO YOU HAVE THE LATEST VERSION?

Comment: I'm using the Header Image Slider plugin which uses Nivo...WordPress doesn't indicate that there's an update. Are you referring to the Nivo slider?

Comment: yes the Nivo Slider's website.. http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/

Comment: I'll give it a try, hopefully it won't break my site. Thanks for your help.